# ASP.NET MVC Check if there is a change in the model for an If statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement

I am trying to put some validation logic into my controller but I'm having a little trouble.

Here's the code:

```
 if (holidayRequestForm.Approved == true)
       {
        TempData["msgAlreadyApproved"] = "This Holiday Has already been approved";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "HolidayRequestFroms");
       }
```

My problem is I want to throw an error message for when a user attempts to approve a holiday request that has already been approved but obviously, the code above will throw the message when any holiday gets set to approved.

How would I go by checking if a change happens in the model and then throwing the temp message if no change has taken place?

thanks

Comment: I guess you would need to get the current value of the record from your database, and compare the value to that.

Comment: So I have this in HTTP Post, How would I get the "Pre" Values?

Comment: Did you save `holidayRequestForm.Approved` in your database if user first approved?

Comment: Like I said, assuming the existing value is already stored somewhere on the server, like in a database, then get the existing value from there. Presumably, if the holiday is already approved, there must be a record of that saved somewhere? Or a record of the pending request, if it isn't already approved? Otherwise how did it get into your page for approval in the first place?

Comment: @D-Shih Yes, there already stored

Comment: @ADyson Alright Cool!

Comment: Load the existing data from database before updating with the data sent in